# Can't echo PHP variable

Tags: php, database, variables, content-management-system, echo

I am trying to build up a CMS. I don't want to use a template, I want to do things a bit more advanced and therefore I will need to make many tables and many rows to achieve the same effect because each page will have a different design.

So, in the index.php I have 7 text fields that I want to be able to be updated via RTE. So I created a table called "page_hem1" on my database where those 7 text fields exist with the names "text1", "text2", etc.

Then I made some basic code for that:

```
// Query the body section for the proper page
$sqlCommand = "SELECT text1 FROM page_hem WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $body1 = $row["text1"];
    $body2 = $row["text2"];
    $body3 = $row["text3"];
    $body4 = $row["text4"];
    $body5 = $row["text5"];
    $body6 = $row["text6"];
    $body7 = $row["text7"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

My issue is that only the $body1 variable is being echoed. Why aren't the others? What am I doing wrong? You should know that I also tried to repeat the same code sequence for each and every single one of the "$body" variables, but it didn't work out neither. Perhaps i didn't repeat in the right way?

What can I do to echo all the $body's?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it obvious that after selecting only `text1`, no other columns such as `text2`, `text3`, etc will be present?

Comment: what is text2, text3 ? You don't select them

Comment: BTW, you're using `mysqli`, which is a good start, but you've still got a massive injection vulnerability. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Suddenly I feel stupid Royal BG... a huge thanks! Still, I have to say that I am not a PHP expert... just a beginner...

Comment: I certainly will Wooble! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only mistake is that you do select only "text1" not all text columns.

```
// Query the body section for the proper page
$sqlCommand = "SELECT text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7 FROM page_hem WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $body1 = $row["text1"];
    $body2 = $row["text2"];
    $body3 = $row["text3"];
    $body4 = $row["text4"];
    $body5 = $row["text5"];
    $body6 = $row["text6"];
    $body7 = $row["text7"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job! Feel so stupid... that is what happens when you are a beginner...

Comment: np. everybody was a beginner and a good start is always SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because you only select one column

wrong (at least here, because you need other columns than just text1)

```
"SELECT text1  FROM page_hem ...
```

better (just get all, but avoid)

```
"SELECT * FROM page_hem
```

correct (only the ones you need)

```
"SELECT text1, text2, ... FROM page_hem
```

Comment: Well than read below, it wasn't meant like that and is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve text1, text2 and so on.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7 FROM page_hem WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7 FROM page_hem WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $body1 = $row["text1"];
    $body2 = $row["text2"];
    $body3 = $row["text3"];
    $body4 = $row["text4"];
    $body5 = $row["text5"];
    $body6 = $row["text6"];
    $body7 = $row["text7"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query);
```